# Scala - extractor unapply confusion

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm attempting to write an extractor(s) for use in matching against a multiple parameter case class.  Simplified example:

```
case class X(p1: String, p2: Int)
```

I'd like each extractor objects to define a fixed value for p1, and p2 is defined on use.  (A,B, etc cannot be a case class and subclass X, and I would also like to use X(*,*) as a case)
Example with apply method:

```
object A {
  def apply(p2: Int): X = X("A", p2)
}

object B {
  def apply(p2: Int): X = X("B", p2)
}

...
```

For pattern matching, I would like them to match like this:

```
X("A", 2) match {
  case A(2) => true // <- should match: p1="A" and p2=2
  case A(_) => true // <- should match: p1="A" and p2=_
  case X("A", _) => true // <- should match: p1="A" and p2=_
  case A(1) => false // <- should not match
  case B(2) => false // <- should not match: p1="B" and p2=2
}
```

I know I need to define `unapply` method in `A`, `B`, etc., but I'm thoroughly confused what the signature and logic should be:

```
object A {
  def unapply(x: ???): Option[???] = {
    ???
  } 
}
```

Assistance, please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`unapply` takes an Any and returns an `Option` of whatever you want to extract. In your case this would be:

```
scala> case class X(p1: String, p2: Int)
defined class X

scala> object A {
     |   def unapply(target: Any): Option[Int] =
     |     PartialFunction.condOpt(target) {
     |       case X("A", p2) => p2
     |     }
     | }
defined module A

scala> val A(x) = X("A", 1)
x: Int = 1

scala> val A(x) = X("B", 1)
scala.MatchError: X(B,1) (of class X)
...
```

But to be honest, the example you came up with could be rewritten without `A` and `B`:

```
X("A",2) match {
  case X("A", 2) => true
  case X("A", 1) => false
  case X("A", _) => true
  case X("B", 2) => false
}
```

Comment: In the first example, I often use `PartialFunction.condOpt`to avoid writting the default case of an unapply (here: `PartialFunction.condOpt(target) {case X("A", p2) => Some(p2)}`; youcan also import `PartialFunction._`).

Comment: So simple!  Thanks!  BTW I know this example could be written like that, but this example is simplified.  Main purpose of the extractors are to encapsulate parameter combinations that aren't easily recalled.

Comment: @HeikoSeeberger may be we can add the PartialFunction example to the answer, in order to give it more visibility (i could edit it but it's your yanswer, so it's up to you) ;)

Comment: I'd like to add that for a case class without parameters, unapply returns a `Boolean`.

Comment: `unapply` can take a typed argument (that is, something more restrictive than `Any`), even a type parameter!

Comment: @Nicolas Only case classes without a parameter list are deprecated, not case classes with an empty parameter list.